# Links wont scroll to different sections after reopening the slide menu

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slide menu that appears on smaller screens and it has three links that go to different sections.

The problem is the links will only work the first time you open the slide menu. If you close it then open it again, it wont go anywhere.

JS Code:

```
function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('sideMenu').style.width = '250px';
}

function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('sideMenu').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('sideMenu').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

}
```

demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/mnuao49k/2/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to delete the function inside `closeSlideMenu()` because it prevent the click on the links, also, since you are not redirecting to another page, this anchor elements can be just  elements.

```js
// Slide Menu

function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('sideMenu').style.width = '250px';
}

function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('sideMenu').style.width = '0';
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  const nav = document.querySelector('.navBar');

  if (window.pageYOffset > 43) {

    nav.style.position = "fixed";
    nav.style.backgroundColor = "black";



  } else {
    nav.style.position = "absolute";
    nav.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Start of navbar  */
.navBar {
  display: grid;
  height: 63px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 150px 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "logo center navbar";
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.navBar .logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: start;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.navBar .logo a {
  color: lavender;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.navBar .logo a:hover {
  color: #4484CE;
  transition: .8s;
}

.navLinks {
  grid-area: navbar;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: end;
  text-align: center;
}

.navLinks a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lavender;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navLinks a:hover {
  color: #4484CE;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

/* Start of Slide Menu */
.openSlide {
  display: grid;
}

.openSlide a {
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 6px;

}

.sideNav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: .8;

}

.sideNav a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: lavender;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sideNav a:hover {
  color: #4484CE;
}

.sideNav .btnClose {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 22px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.about {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "middle2";
  background-color: #4484ce;
  height: 450px;
  align-content: center;

}

.product {
  background-color: lavender;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}

.contact {
  background-color: lavender;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  height: 400px;
}



@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .openSlide {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {


  .navBar .logo {
    grid-area: center;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
  }

  .navLinks {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="topPage">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="navBar" id="top">
      <span class="openSlide">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
          <svg width="30" height="30">
            <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="5"></path>
            <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="5"></path>
            <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="5"></path>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#topPage">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navLinks">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#product">Products</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div id="sideMenu" class="sideNav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnClose" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#product">Products</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="about">
      <h1 id="about">This is about section</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <h1 id="product">This is products section</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <h1 id="contact">This is contact section</h1>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```